# How can I use a React context variable when initiating i18next interpolation?

Tags: reactjs, i18next, string-interpolation

The React app I'm working on is using `react-18next`. Inside the `index.js` file, there is a `i18n.js` file imported into it that configures and initiates `i18n`.

This includes `interpolation` configuration where we have some various formats for strings and numbers.

**i18n.js**

```
import i18n from 'i18next';

i18n.init({
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false,
    format: (value, format) => {

      if(format === 'currency') {
        return return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-Us', {
          maximumFractionDigits: decimals,
          style: 'currency',
          currency: 'USD',
        }).format(value);
      } 
    }
  }
});
```

I have a React context variable `currency` that I'd like to use in this `interpolation` function to replace "USD." How can I do that?

In order to access the context variable, I need to use the `useContext()` hook, which is unavailable inside this `i18n.js` file, as it needs to be called inside a React component.

The context variable changes, based on someone using a `<select>` input, so I would think the `interpolation` function would need to be re-instantiated each time the variable changes.

I tried moving `i18n.init()` into a custom hook and calling that hook from my `App.js` component.

**useI18n.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import i18n from 'i18next';

import { ContextCurrency } from 'context';

const useI18n = () => {
  const { currency } = useContext(ContextCurrency);

  // init i18n when currency changes
  useEffect(() => {
    i18n.init(...);
  }, [currency]);

  return i18n;
}

export default useI18n;
```

This resulted in an error:

> Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by App.
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

The error is a check being made in React's `areHookInputsEqual` function. I'm not exactly sure why the error is being thrown but I know it has something to do with the hook I made. Besides, re-initiating `1i18n` each time `currency` changes doesn't seem right.

Note: I am aware that I can instantiate the context variable *in each component* that makes use of the interpolation and pass it as an option to `interpolation.format()`, but that's what I'm trying to avoid. Ideally there would be a way to access this context variable *in one single place* rather than on a per-translation basis.

Answer (score 0):

Like you already assumed, you normally need to pass the currency via t() function like here: https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/formatting#currency

But you could try to use the new formatting functionality `i18next.services.formatter.add` (done after init), but I did not test if this works with context…